# Passing Comments for inclusion in an ABI File

Tags: abi

We are trying to pass additional information about specific actions and data field through to the abi file.   Is there a way to include comments/text in the cpp file that can be passed through and appear in the abi file?

Answer (score 0):

No.

ABI is JSON file, and there is no syntax for comment in its specification.